# How to introduce new operator in java and how it is done in java 8 in lambda expression?

Tags: java, java-8

At a lower level, what kind of changes were made by java 8 to incorporate a new operator "->", though I understand that in normal programming practice we can't overload any existing operator as like in C++.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... the Java compiler was changed, that's all. What makes you think a DSL is involved?

Comment: You cannot add a new operator to Java, Java doesn't support operator overloading. Oracle added the `->` operator to the language as  [JSR 335](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335).

Comment: You changed your question completely, but even now, you are on the wrong track. `C++` allows to overload *existing* operators to work with new types, but it doesn’t allow creating new operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are completely on the wrong track when you think that the “JVM understands” the operators of the Java language. These operators are purely a source code artifact that gets translated to Java byte code by the compiler. For example, in Java source code you can use the operator `+` to concatenate `String`s since the very first version, but the Java byte code never had a direct support for it (up to Java 9).

On the other hand, in the past, all major Java language releases were paired with an update of the JVM, so there never was a requirement for an older JVM to work with newer byte code. While Java 8’s lambda expressions use features already introduced with version 7 of the JVM, the release of Java 8 comes with an updated JVM, which is required for features like non-`abstract` methods in `interface`s, so if lambda expression were requiring new byte code feature, it was no problem either.

That said, the grammar, which must be understood by the *compiler* rather than the JVM, *has changed* to add lambda expressions and method references. Therefore, you need an up to date compiler to use them. There is no DSL support inside Java source code. The closest thing to that, is using annotation based meta programming, but that’s far away from being able to add a new operator to the language.

Comment: What do you mean by `in Java source code you can use the operator + to concatenate Strings since the very first version, but the Java byte code never had a direct support for it (up to Java 9)`? Please point me to some resource, thanks!

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: In case you are referring to “up to Java 9” part, see [`StringConcatFactory`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html). It’s not dedicated byte code instructions, but it’s on par with the JRE’s lambda expression support. Before that, the compiled code had to use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` (since Java 5) under the hood.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link